# Install FTC SDK in Gitpod/VS Code

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, gradle, sdk, gitpod

Some background:
FTC (First Tech Challenge) is a competitive robotics league that uses Android-based software to make a robot function. In my organization, a majority of programmers come from our school and thus, they often find themselves programming on school-issued Chromebooks with restrictive software. Normally, we would program on Android Studio and it would work perfectly fine. By using Gitpod though, we can essentially have an unrestricted IDE on those computers and thus, I began trying to make this work.

Basically, how can I use the SDK in Gitpod or in VS Code (since they both use VS Code Browser)?

Clone [this repository](https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/FtcRobotController.git).
Add `.gitpod.yml` and `.gitpod.Dockerfile` files and add correct code in there
Install Android SDK via `apt-get install android-sdk`
Install Command Line Tools by cloning the .zip folder and extracting it to the correct place
Build the project with `./gradlew build` (build runs out of JVM memory)
Type out `Mo` and see if intellisense suggests `MotorEx`, a class in the SDK.
Fail :(

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/1273

Comment: @MorrisonChang I thought so too, but should be able to do something similar is VS Code as well.

Comment: As Android Studio is continuously updated, VS Code may be a poor substitute as talked about in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/w8cr8r/developing_android_apps_with_visual_studio_code/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) I hope you realize that with a cloud env you won't be able to live debug the android app on your robot without a connecting PC. Just making sure you asked/checked with the school admin to enable the chromebooks if devices are able to support [Linux/AStudio on chromebook](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#chrome-os).